# How is the @ sign escaped in a Loki log query?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

The JSON log messages I would like to query have fields with `@` sign in the log property like these:

```json
 "log": {
    "@t": "2023-06-26T15:30:31.3379302Z",
    "@mt": "Exception calling data source {Source}",
    "@l": "Error",
    "Source" : "Source01"
    ...
```

I can search for Source01 with:
`... | json | log_Source=`Source`

And that works great. I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax to search for one of the fields with @ sign. For example, how would I search for @l = `Error`? If I try log_@l = Error it's a syntax error.

I

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on the answer just after posting this question.

Use _ in place of the @ sign.

```
... | json | log__l = `Error`
```

So we need 2 underscores. One for the nesting of @l within log and another for the @ symbol.

This matches the log entries as expected using the Grafana explorer query builder. The match is not highlighted in the results listing. Not a big deal on that.